# Sending form data to vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to send the result from a number input to a js function, and can't seem to make it work. I have tried with some answers from other questions in the site, but was still unable.
My code goes something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="example">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="how(example)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function how(example){
alert("example");
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.value` to get the value of a text/number input or textarea element.

```js
const numInput = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]')
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(numInput.value);
  });
```

```html
<input type="number" name="example">
<input type="button" value='click'>
```

Try to use `addEventListener` rather than HTML-inline-eval handlers, or on*-handlers; keeping all of your Javascript in the Javascript itself is helpful and is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

Give the id of your number input. May be it will useful.

```
<input type="number" name="example" id="example">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="how()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function how(){
        var number = $('#example').val();
        alert(number);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Vanilla, not Jquery

Answer (score 0):

This might help you (this code will make it so that it alerts the value in number):

```js
function alertval(){
  alert(document.getElementById("example").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="example" id="example">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="alertval()">
```